# How can I search along a route and filter the results on Here categories

Tags: here-api

I want to be able to filter the places found based on Here categories when travelling along a route.

You can partially do that with the current discovery API and using the query text. But that will only allow you to filter on one query string, not a set of Here categories.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this? Is it possible?

The only other alternative I can see is looping around a number of categories (textual, not Here) and call the API for each category. And then merge the results. Becomes pretty expensive if you have many categories. Seem unnecessary since the filtering functionality is available in the Here platform.

I have tried the current discovery API and I cannot even get it to work. Have another questions about that fact.

Reading the manual, it seems like this should be possible, but not when you look into the details.

From the manual: This tutorial demonstrates how to search for places by category within a corridor.
[Manual](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/dev_guide/topics-api/code-discover-route.html)

But the category mentioned here is not the Here category, but any text you enter in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Please be informed that the discovery endpoint doesn't support searching along the route and filtering by HERE categories. We suggest you to try the browse endpoint which supports filtering the results by categories along the route.